# Chip implants in humans and an encrypted cube

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I remember some scene when someone connects to a computer and put on some glasses and gets some 3d interface or something like that.

I think I remember some kind of cube that he tries to open as some kind of encryption.

Pretty sure that there was chip implants there too

Comment: Any clue how old it was - when you watched it, was it in the theatre or on TV?

Comment: You should be more informative before posting `identify-movie` questions.At least when you saw it,if it is `animation`,`black-white` or `color` etc. These things can be covered easily!

Comment: not sure about these specific examples as it seems trivial that if not mentioned then it's not b&w/animated etc (but it was my first post here so I might be wrong). but I did forget to mention time approximation.
anyways, thanks for trying to identify :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be any number of Virtual Reality movies.

Possibly [Johnny Mnemonic (1995)](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm51296512/tt0113481) with Keanu Reeves.  Johnny is an information courier, carrying data in a chip implanted in his head. It has several scenes with virtual reality glasses and connecting to networks etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Surrogates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogates_%28film%29) by [Bruce Willis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Willis). It is a 2009 sci-fi film. Here the humans can connect to computers and wear glasses and they live within artificial robots where they look more beautiful and alive. The robots also had chips in their heads. Although I could not remember the cube scene.

Comment: um... they weren't miniatures, they were full blown robotic replicas (depending on the quality of the unit).  also, those that used them didn't have chips in them, they resided in a sort of chamber that connected them to the surrogate

Comment: No the users did not have chips in their heads, rather the robots had!